# How to display search results in laravel from table data?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, laravel

so I have a table with 2 columns and I got search functionality from tutorial but it does not function on the table that I made. the search function works in real-time, as soon as user start inputting it displays results that are similar until the input matches exactly a single data. it worked when I copied exactly from tutorial but could not make it to work for my table, please help

here is how my table looks like inside `post/index.blade.php` which extends `layouts.app` that contains the scripts

```
<table class="..." id="table">
      <thead>
      <tr>
        <th>No.</th>
        <th>Student ID</th>
        <th>Student Name</th>
        <th>
          <a href="#" class="create-modal btn btn-success btn-sm">
            <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></i>
          </a>
        </th>
      </tr>
      </thead>
      <tbody>
      {{ csrf_field() }}
      <?php  $no=1; ?>
      @foreach ($post as $value)
        <tr class="post{{$value->id}}">
          <td>{{ $no++ }}</td>
          <td>{{ $value->student_id }}</td>
          <td>{{ $value->student_name }}</td>
          <td>
            <a class="show-modal btn btn-info btn-sm" 
            data-id="{{$value->id}}" 
            data-student_id="{{$value->student_id}}" 
            data-student_name="{{$value->student_name}}"
            >
              <i class="fa fa-eye"></i>
            </a>
            <a class="edit-modal btn btn-warning btn-sm" 
            data-id="{{$value->id}}" 
            data-student_id="{{$value->student_id}}" 
            data-student_name="{{$value->student_name}}"
            >
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></i>
            </a>
            <a  class="delete-modal btn btn-danger btn-sm" 
            data-id="{{$value->id}}" 
            data-student_id="{{$value->student_id}}" 
            data-student_name="{{$value->student_name}}"
            >
              <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></i>
            </a>
          </td>
        </tr>
        </tbody>
      @endforeach
    </table>
```

and the searching action inside Controller

```
function action(Request $request)
    {
     if($request->ajax())
     {
      $output = '';
      $query = $request->get('query');
      if($query != '')
      {
       $data = DB::table('posts')
         ->where('student_id', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')
         ->orWhere('student_name', 'like', '%'.$query.'%')        
         ->orderBy('student_id', 'desc')
         ->get();
         
      }
      else
      {
       $data = DB::table('posts')
         ->orderBy('student_id', 'desc')
         ->get();
      }
      $total_row = $data->count();
      if($total_row > 0)
      {
       foreach($data as $row)
       {
        $output .= '
        <tr>
         <td>'.$row->student_id.'</td>
         <td>'.$row->student_name.'</td>         
        </tr>
        ';
       }
      }
      else
      {
       $output = '
       <tr>
        <td align="center" colspan="5">No Data Found</td>
       </tr>
       ';
      }
      $data = array(
       'table_data'  => $output,
       'total_data'  => $total_row
      );

      echo json_encode($data);
     }
    }
}
```

and this is the script inside `layouts/app.blade.php` to make the search function

```
//  search function
$(document).ready(function(){

 fetch_customer_data();

 function fetch_customer_data(query = '')
 {
  $.ajax({
   url:"{{ route('post.action') }}",
   method:'GET',
   data:{query:query},
   dataType:'json',
   success:function(data)
   {
    $('tbody').html(data.table_data);
    $('#total_records').text(data.total_data);
   }
  })
 }

 $(document).on('keyup', '#search', function(){
  var query = $(this).val();
  fetch_customer_data(query);
 });
});
```

and I added the route for search inside route group

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
  Route::resource('post','PostController');
  Route::get('post/action', 'PostController@action')->name('post.action');
});
```

and this is how the index looks like inside Controller

```
class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function index(){
      $post = Post::paginate(4);
      return view('post.index',compact('post'));
    }
```

my url looks like this `sms.test/post`

Comment: why not Datatable?

Comment: yeah it's database. all data are stored from database @MasudulHasanShawon

Comment: did you check content of `data` ? what does it brings back?

Comment: @Swati if you mean this `$data = DB::table('posts')` in the controller, I assume it returns the content of table `posts` but I'm not sure if it actually does and I don't know how to check if it does or not :(

Answer (score 0):

after half day of trial and error it was my route that's wrong

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['web']], function() {
  Route::resource('post','PostController');
  Route::get('post/action', 'PostController@action')->name('post.action');
});
```

I romoved `post/` from this `Route::get('post/action', 'PostController@action')->name('post.action');`

so now it looks like this `Route::get('action', 'PostController@action')->name('post.action');`

I do not understand why but it's working now lol